# pitch accent of "compound" verbs

Tags: pitch-accent

Lets say this: 大人びて見える, 大人びる and 見える are 中高, but does the pitch change? or is it the same?

and for stem of verb + another verb, like 倒れこむ, 嚙みちぎる etc, do they change the pitch when in those combinations? or do they stay the same?